# Switching between images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I have a little script in js that changes images over time and I wanted to add two buttons that allow to skip through images if someone doesn't want to wait, but they don't really work and clicking on them only brings me back to the first image.

Here's the script I found for changing images over time:

```
<script>
var imageSources = ["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png"];
var index = 0;
setInterval (function(){
  if (index === imageSources.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("image").src = imageSources[index];
  index++;
} , 2000);
```

Here's the script I tried to make for changing them on click:

```
 function changeImage1() {
        if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image1.png") 
        {
        document.getElementById("image").src = "image3.png";    
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image2.png")
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "image1.png";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image3.png")
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "image2.png";
    }
    else {}
 }
function changeImage2() {
        if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image1.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "image2.png";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image2.png")
        {
            document.getElementById("image").src = "image3.png";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("image").src == "image3.png"){
            document.getElementById("image").src = "image1.png";
        }
        else {}
    }
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<button name="button1" id="button1" onclick="changeImage1()">
<img src="arrow_left.png" width="50px" height="50px"/>
</button>
<img name="image" id="image" src="image1.png" width="800px" height="300px"/>
<button name="button2" id="button2" onclick="changeImage2()">
<img src="arrow_right.png" onclick="changeImage2()" width="50px" height="50px"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### soo I think you want a button to skip the image and a button to bring the previous image.

**First let's declare the variables**

```
const img = document.getElementById("image"); // the img element 
const imageSources = ["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png"];
let index = 0;
let travel; // here the most important thing
```

**you have to create a start function so u can call it when the page load or reset the timer**

```
const startTravel = () => {
    travel = setInterval(() => {
      ++index;
      if (index < 0 || index === imageSources.length) index = 0;
      img.src = imageSources[index];
    }, 2000);
};
```

**the next image function be like**

```
const changeImage2 = () => {
  clearInterval(travel);
  img.src = imageSources[++index];
  startTravel();
}
```

**the previous image function be like**

```
const changeImage1 = () => {
  clearInterval(travel);
  img.src = imageSources[--index];
  startTravel();
}
```

**it's not done yet when u click skip 5 times its will set the index to 6 and 6 is not in imageSources soo I don wanna do it for you cus its easy i thing you have to make it**

**full code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button1" onclick="changeImage1()">
    left
</button>

<img src="image1.jpg" alt="img" id="img">

<button id="button2" onclick="changeImage2()">
    right
</button>

<script>
  const img = document.getElementById("img");
  const imageSources = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];
  let index = 0;
  let travel;

  const startTravel = () => {
    travel = setInterval(() => {
      ++index;

      console.log(index);
      if (index < 0 || index === imageSources.length) index = 0;
      img.src = imageSources[index];
    }, 6000);
  };

  const changeImage1 = () => {
    if (index === 0) index = imageSources.length;

    clearInterval(travel);
    img.src = imageSources[--index];
    startTravel();
  }

  const changeImage2 = () => {
    if (index === imageSources.length - 1) index = -1;

    clearInterval(travel);
    img.src = imageSources[++index];
    startTravel();
  }

  startTravel();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing is....I copied and pasted your code and the images are not changing and buttons don't do anything. If I understand your script correctly "onclick='changeImage2()'" in the button attributes should probably work but it doesn't sooo...I have no idea im a noobie sorry

Comment: maybe I have to create full HTML for ya and try copying it

Comment: Great! Works pretty fine and I pretty much fixed the problem with indexes but when I click skip it goes through 2 images instead of one
if (index <= 0) { index = 3; } (changeImage1)
if (index >= 3) { index = 0; } (changeImage2)
These are the only lines I added and I don't really understand why it's skipping 2 instead of 1.

Comment: ill do everything and add it into the full HTML code check it out now (:

Answer (score 0):

The thing is,

```
  if (index === imageSources.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
```

this line of code, or three lines of code, waits for the imageSources length to become 3, but the imageSources start counting at 1, so if the imageSources variable contains 3 elements, the length will be three. However indexing is done by 0s so you would have to change your code to

```
  if (index === (imageSources.length - 1)) {
    index = 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for functionality that resembles a slider. The first snippet you show with the `setInterval` is a good place to work from. Iterating through a list makes your code dynamic and allows for items to be added or removed without having to change too much code.

I've expanded on your provided code and made a workable snippet down below. Be sure to check it out.

Instead of an `setInterval` I've used `setTimeout`. The reason for this is because the both the buttons and the loop use the same function to display the current image. So the loop will be able to call itself again. And when the loop is called before 2 seconds have passed, it will be canceled and started again. This might happen when you click one of the buttons.

I've removed the inline `onclick` listeners in favor of using `addEventListener` in JavaScript. I would advice you to adopt this method. It will allow you to repeat less code, keep your JavaScript in one place and make your code more flexible.
I did however add a `value` attribute to the buttons. Buttons support this attribute. It can carry a small load of information, like telling you if this button is the previous or next button. The `value` attribute can be easily read with the `value` property of a `HTMLButtonElement` object (which is the JS equivalent of a `<button>`).

Be sure to ask any questions if you have them as I assume that some things might be new to you.

```js
// The element to display the image with.
const imageElement = document.querySelector('.js-image-display');

// The buttons to go previous and next.
const imageButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-image-control');

// Available sources of images.
const imageSources = [
  "https://www.placecage.com/c/800/300", 
  "https://www.placecage.com/800/300",
  "https://www.fillmurray.com/800/300",
  "https://www.placecage.com/g/800/300",
  "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/800/300"
];

// Current displayed image.
let currentImageIndex = 0;

// Variable to store the loop in.
let currentLoop;

// Show first image and start looping.
showCurrentImage();

/**
 * Cancel previous loop, wait for 2 seconds and call nextImage().
 * nextImage() will then call showCurrentImage which will call
 * loop() again. This will keep the cycle going.
 */
function loop() {
  clearTimeout(currentLoop);
  currentLoop = setTimeout(nextImage, 2000);
}

/**
 * Update the src of the imageElement with the 
 * current image index. Then reset the loop.
 */
function showCurrentImage() {
  imageElement.src = imageSources[currentImageIndex];
  loop();
}

/**
 * Remove 1 from the current image index
 * or go back to the end. Then show the image.
 */
function prevImage() {
  if (currentImageIndex === 0) {
    currentImageIndex = imageSources.length - 1;
  } else {
    currentImageIndex--;
  }
  showCurrentImage();
}

/**
 * Add 1 to current image index or go 
 * back to the start. Then show the image.
 */
function nextImage() {
  if (currentImageIndex === imageSources.length - 1) {
    currentImageIndex = 0;
  } else {
    currentImageIndex++;
  }
  showCurrentImage();
}

// Link the prev and next words to their corresponding functions.
// This way you don't have to write a lot of if / else statements
// to get the function based on the value of the button.
const actionMap = {
  'prev': prevImage,
  'next': nextImage
}

/**
 * Decide by reading the value attribute if nextImage or
 * prevImage should be called. event.currentTarget is one
 * of the two buttons that you've clicked. It gets the value
 * and looks up the function to call from the actionMap.
 *
 * @param {Event} event Click event triggerd by the buttons.
 */
function onButtonClick(event) {
  const value = event.currentTarget.value;
  const action = actionMap[value];
  action();
}

// Loop over the buttons and add an click event listener
// for each button in the list. In some older browser imageButtons
// might not be able to use forEach, so Array.from() turns it
// into an array so we know for sure that forEach is possible.
Array.from(imageButtons).forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Prev button -->
<button class="js-image-control" value="prev">Previous</button>

<!-- Image -->
<img class="js-image-display" src="image1.png" width="800" height="300"/>

<!-- Next button -->
<button class="js-image-control" value="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: ggz man your code does it all. It's sad that I don't even understand it even tho you literally explained every single step. Gonna reread that a few thousand times till I get it. Thanks a lot for all the effort man really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask any questions as Stack Overflow is a place where you can learn.